# variable substitution shell script issue KSH

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

hello I am trying you achieve the below

```
i=1
wwn1=hi
```

i should be able to echo the value in wwn$i. The below code fails. Please help

```
echo 'wwn$i'
```

Above prints

```
wwn$i
```

it should print 'hi'

Comment: Not exactly elegant, but works in bash and ksh alike: `eval echo $(echo '$'wwn$i)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have ksh here, so I can not verify the ksh solution

```
typeset -n x=wwn$i
echo "$x"
# or
eval "echo \$$wwn$i"
```

With bash you (other readers) could do

```
x=wwn$i
echo "${!x}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval echo \$wwn$i
```

or

```
eval echo '$wwn'$i
```